# android listView getCheckedPosition returns wrong SparseBooleanArray

Tags: android, listview

I'm using listview with ArrayAdapter and have following code:

```
     final SparseBooleanArray checked = listViewFilters.getCheckedItemPositions();

    if (checked.size() == listViewFilters.getAdapter().getCount()) {
        //all is selected
    } else {
        //collect each value
    }
```

All worked fine until I needed all items to be selected from start. So I added this code for selecting all items:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < listViewFilters.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
           listViewFilters.setItemChecked(i, true);
     }
```

After adding above code, if I checked off some items, checked.size() = count of all items anyway. Expected result is - checked.size() < count.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you have to POST your whole adapter code .Nobody identify what mistake you did in the code......May be some little mistake ....

Comment: After you checked some items do you update your SparseBooleanArray?

Comment: no, `checked.size()` does not change: only the content inside changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well. `listView.getCheckedItemCount()` works fine.
It's weird to see that `listView.getCheckedItemCount()` returns different value than `listView.getCheckedItemPositions().size()` only after `setItemChecked(i, true)`

Answer (score 0):

`getCheckedItemPositions` might prove to be a little tricky. As you noticed, based on the interaction with the `ListView`, it might return different results.
Short version: once you selected and deselected an item, that item is still returned by `getCheckedItemPositions`, with a value of false. So you need to actually read the values from the keys instead of relying on the size.

Comment: that's why asked this question. I need to rely only on the size. I solved it. Thanks anyway.